# I'm working with lxml.html Adding new tags in the HTML file and then manipulating it but it doesn't seems to be working

Tags: html-parsing, lxml, lxml.html

```
for y in row_data:
    say = html.fromstring(
        str(html.tostring(y)).lstrip("b'").replace('">', '"><span>').replace('</td>', '</span></td>').rstrip("'"))
    y.addprevious(say)
    y.getparent().remove(y)


#[x.attrib['style'] for x in row_data if number.search(x.text_content()) and not date_pattern.search(x.text_content())]
for x in row_data:
    if number.search(x.text_content()) and not date_pattern.search(x.text_content()):
        x.attrib['style'] = x.attrib['style']+"color:orange;"
        #x.set('<span class="Numbers">', value=x.text_content())
        x.set('class="Numbers"', value=x.text_content())

    elif date_pattern.findall(x.text_content()):
        x.attrib['style'] = x.attrib['style']+"color:red;"
        x.set('class="Dates"', value=x.text_content())
```

Comment: I'm working on a tabular HTML file which contains TD's and TR's. I've used the below snippet to extract the values
# Getting HTML element cell wise
for row in range(1, len(tr_elements)):
    table_tr = tr_elements[row]
    # print(table_tr)
    #     column_count = 0
    for column in table_tr.iterchildren():
        #         print(len(table_tr.iterchildren()))
        data = column.text_content()
        if data != u'\xa0':
            if data != '$':
                #print(type(data))
                row_data.append(column)

Comment: # Getting HTML element cell wise
for row in range(1, len(tr_elements)):
    table_tr = tr_elements[row]

    for column in table_tr.iterchildren():

        data = column.text_content()
        if data != u'\xa0':
            if data != '$':

                row_data.append(column)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.